# node-rdkafka is throwing segmentation fault

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, apache-kafka, libssl

I am trying to migrate the Kafka library being used in my application from kafka-node to node-rdkafka. My application is running on EC2 with Ubuntu 14 version and the node version is 12.14.0. I have tried two version's of node-rdkafka (2.10.0 & 2.10.1). Both the versions are throwing segmentation fault while deployment.

This is the error I am getting in gdb

```
Thread 16 "rdk:broker-1" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffce7fc700 (LWP 32445)]
0x00007fffdd81ba9b in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

What could be the possible cause for this issue?

Comment: Have you asked the maintainer of the package by filing an issue? https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/issues  This looks like a version mismatch between the native ssl (encrypted transport) library and something else.  And, Ubuntu 14 reached end-of-life at the end of April 2019.  You might want to try a more recent version of Ubuntu, or pay Ubuntu for [extended security maintenance](https://ubuntu.com/security/esm).

Comment: I tried with an instance of ubuntu 18 version as well. There also I was getting the same error and backtrace

Comment: "This looks like a version mismatch between the native ssl (encrypted transport) library and something else" : Could you pls explain this more. As I am new to it. How to verify this?